# Do I need the array('%s', '%s') in a WordPress statement (query) or is obsolete?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Please forgive my ignorance, I've been learning how to develop WordPress plugins and I'm dabbling in database queries.

Meanwhile, I was developing one of these I found this syntax for a query, actually the same concept twice, written in two different ways:

```
$wpdb->insert(
    $table_name,
    array(
        'name' => $name,
        'lat'  => $lat,
        'lng'  => $lng,
        array('%s', '%s')
);

$wpdb->update(
    $table_name,
    array(
        'name' => $name,
        'lat'  => $lat,
        'lng'  => $lng,
    array('%s'),
    array('%s')
);
```

First thing first, my question is if I need the array( '%s' ) to specify that is a string (is a sort of binding the value to prevent injection?) or can I skip it. And secondly, is there any difference between the two queries? Is the second one wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @WPDeveloper [`dabble` is a perfectly valid word](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dabble), and OP's use of it in their question was correct.  I rolled back your edit of that word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First thing first, my question is if I need the array( '%s' ) to specify that is a string (is a sort of binding the value to prevent injection?) or can I skip it.**

You can avoid format array(array( '%s' )) in both syntax. It is an optional parameter for query. You can find it from below links:

1) [WPDB Insert](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/)

2) [WPDB Update](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/update/)

**And secondly, is there any difference between the two queries? Is the second one wrong?**

For your second question, your first query inserts data into database & second updates data for all rows in database. Here you can avoid where parameter if you want to update all data of your table.

Comment: Great! My second question is actually if there is any difference between:

array('%s', '%s') and array('%s'), array('%s'). You're right, that's an update statement so my query failed

Comment: Yes there is a difference between: array('%s', '%s') and array('%s'), array('%s').